# Why WGS-84 1-second grid strokes are not drawing in QGIS (3.20.2)?

Tags: qgis, error, grids-graticules

I have a project in the Mercator projection (QGIS (3.20.2)). I created a layout of the future map, where I adjusted the coordinate grid (WGS-84). Added 1 second, but part of its interval is no longer displayed on a part of the map. What could be the problem? I enclose a picture where everything is as it should be in the green zone, but there are no strokes in the red.[image]

Comment: Can you provide the layout for download?

Comment: Can you provide an email address?